# What is the difference between dbcc checks and suspect pages table in terms of data page corruption?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, corruption, dbcc-checkdb, dbcc

Dbcc checkdb returns errors if it detects corruption on data pages.

Similarly the suspect pages table hold corruption info of data pages.

What is the difference between dbcc checks and suspect pages table in terms of data page corruption?

Answer (score 1):

The suspect pages table is populated when corrupted pages are accessed, that could by a page read for example or the dbcc checkdb process (that checks all of the pages).